# Regular expression to select only the line that contain two searched words?

Tags: regex

I am not very advanced with regular expression so i am not sure how to do this. Let say i have a text file that contain more then 1000 lines of data. I want to search for the words 'command' and 'find'. They occur on many places throughout the whole document but only on line 100 they occur on the same line, for example: `The linux command to search files and folders is find.`
Let say i don't know the order of these two words, where they are placed, inside the line.

Is it possible, using regular expression, to select directly this line, when searching for 'command' and 'find', and ignore other lines where the words only occur once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `^.*(command|find).*$` in Sublime text (as I tried this in ST3, on Windows 10).
My answer is based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006093/regular-expression-to-search-multiple-strings-textpad) in stack overflow.

EDIT: The RE above allows "command" OR "find" not insisting on BOTH. On the other hand, it let unneeded expressions such as "commander", "finding" or "viewfinder" be in the result.

```
(\<command\>.*\<find\>)|(\<find\>.*\<command\>)
```

eliminates these false hits.
Note the \< and > sequences which mean the beginning and end of a word.

Comment: I tested this in Notepad++, i don't have Sublime Text, but it didn't work. I mean it selects also lines that contain only 'command' or 'find'.

Comment: (\<command\>.*\<find\>)|(\<find\>.*\<command\>)  will server you well.

Comment: @GombaiSándor, feel free to edit my answer or post your answer. I tried your regex, it works for me

Comment: @peter7558, Gombai Sandor edited my answer to make it work. All due credits to Sandor!

Answer (score 1):

In `vim`, you can use `.*\<command\>\&.*\<find\>`. 
As indicated by Gombai Sándor, `\<…\>` delimits words,
so, if you just want to search for the *strings* "command" and "find"
(even if they occur as part of larger words, e.g., "commander")
you can leave out the `\<` and `\>`.

Reference: [gvim search query for mixed AND & OR conditions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256719/80216).

Note: this has the minor drawback that it will leave the cursor
at the beginning of the line (that contains both of the words)
and not on either of the searched-for words themselves
(unless it appears at the beginning of the line).

Answer (score 0):

FIND:

`^.*(?i-s)(COMMAND).*?(FIND).*$|(?2).*?(?1)`

or:

`(?i-s)^.*\W(COMMAND\W.*\WFIND|FIND\W.*\WCOMMAND)\W.*\R`